# Why do my test functions appear in code coverage? (or how to make them 100%?)

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, xunit.net

I'm using xUnit to test my C# code and I'm using Visual Studio Premium 2012.

In my solution I have my main project that I'm testing and a 2nd project that contains all of my tests. I'm supposesd to be at 100% code coverage, but there are some functions in my Test project that I cannot get to 100%. Can I just exclude that project from appearing in Code Coverage results?

Or... does anyone now how to get a test function to 100% when you have a test where you are expecting an exception to be thrown? Here are some of the ways I've tried to write a test for a method that should throw an exception and what isn't being covered. MyBusinessLogic has a function named GenerateNameLine that accepts an object of type MyViewModel. if the Name property of MyViewModel is an empty string, it should throw an exception of type RequiredInformationMissingException.

```
[Fact]
public void TestMethod1()
{
  var vm = new MyViewModel();
  vm.Name = string.Empty;

  Assert.Throws<RequiredInformationMissingException>(delegate { MyBusinessLogic.GenerateNameLine(vm); });
}
```

This test passes, but code coverage with color highlighting it showing me that `MyBusinessLogic.GenerateNameLine(vm);` is not getting hit.

I've also tried:

```
[Fact]
public void TestMethod1
{
  bool fRequiredInfoExceptionThrown = false;
  var vm = new MyViewModel();
  vm.Name = string.Empty;

  try
  {
    MyBusinessLogic.GenerateNameLine(vm);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    if (ex.GetType() == typeof(RequiredInformationMissingException))
      fRequiredInfoExceptionThrown = true;
  }

  Assert.True(fRequiredInfoExceptionThrown, "RequiredInformationMissingException was not thrown.");
}
```

This test also passes. But code coverage says the `}` right before my `catch` is never hit.

I don't know how to write a test for an exception that gets 100%. I know it doesn't even really matter, but at work 100% code coverage is part of our definition of done, so I don't know what to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is Yes

We provide filters to customize what you want to include/exclude via the .runsettings file. You can filter out pretty much anything that you do not find useful.
The [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] attribute can also be used in code.

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sudhakan/archive/2012/05/11/customizing-code-coverage-in-visual-studio-11.aspx

Are you seeing the second issue in VS2012RTM+Update1 as well?

Answer (score 0):

I would exclude the tests, but still have an eye on coverage rate for them, because a coverage below 99% would suggest some of them did not run at all.

BTW: 100% is an ideal and cannot be achieved in real life projects. At least the effort to actually reach 100% opposed to something like 90% is disproportionately high. Also exact coverage rates depend on the manner of counting hit lines.

Comment: I would still want to just ignore test code coverage. If some tests aren't making it all the way through then I would know by seeing failed tests, right?

Comment: Yes, you would. I would create a separate coverage report for only the test. That way your see if there is something wrong with your tests (e.g. if you accidentally deleted the Test-Attribute or if there is a abandoned helper function).

Comment: How do you create a separate coverage report? I guess that's actually what I'm trying to do. I don't want to see my test code coverage when I want to see my actual project's code coverage. It was easy to exclude it in VS2010, you just don't click the check box for it in the test settings file. But in VS2012 you don't use a test settings file to choose what code coverage you want.

Comment: I don't know, because I do not use the unit test features built-in in VS.